# is it possible to use cloud 9 and offline IDE at same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, cloud9, aws-cloud9

I'm thinking about traveling, and will have very unstable internet. Anyway I can continue to work on my projects on cloud 9? I got bash, Ubuntu with ruby/rails on Windows so I think I got pretty good working environment, but I don't know how I can work on my pc and then on cloud 9 interchangeably. Thoughts?
Also, how does gems work? If I install gems on rails project on c9, is that installed to the project or to the host pc(i.e. I need to reinstall it everywhere)?
I'm new to programming so I need all the assistance I can get...

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: You cannot. If you search google for "cloud9 offline" you see some feature requests but that's it. This might be a good time to invest in getting a local environment setup, but doing any kind of offline programming can be difficult if, like me, you are highly dependent on google.

Comment: @maxpleaner I personally live 10 years without Google and I am pretty happy. Check [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=max+pleaner&t=canonical&ia=web) :)

Comment: Hi, If you have committed all changes from cloud9 in your repository and you have configured your environment, I guess you could clone your project from GitHub, Bitbucket or wherevere it is